# how to change the path with render

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am working on a django application which contains two forms in two different templates. In the first form an image can be uploaded. Once the image is uploaded an image classifier classifies the image and renders the template with the second form. In the second form some description about the image is filled and the form is submitted. The form is then saved and can be viewed in a different template.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('items/', views.item_list, name='item_list'),
    path('items/upload/', views.upload_image, name='upload_image'),
    path('items/upload/description/', views.upload_item, name='upload_item'),
    path('items/<int:pk>/', views.delete_item, name='delete_item'),
    path('items/upload/image_classification/', views.image_classification, name='image_classification'),
]
```

In the first form after the image is uploaded, the the path becomes `items/upload/image_classification/` and the second form is rendered, which according to urls.py is `path('items/upload/description/', views.upload_item, name='upload_item')`.

The problem I am facing is, when I try to save the second form, the **image_classification** function from views.py runs whereas **upload_item** function should ideally run. This leads to the form not saving.

When I try to load the second form directly without the first form, the path then is `'items/upload/description/'` and the form is saved successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the rest of the code

**views.py**

```
def upload_image(request):
    return render(request, 'upload_image.html')

def upload_item(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_des = ItemForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form_des.is_valid():
            form_des.save()
            return redirect('item_list')
    else:
        form_des = ItemForm()

    return render(request, 'upload_item.html', {'form_des': form_des})

def handle_uploaded_file(file, filename):
    if not os.path.exists('media/classification/'):
        os.mkdir('media/classification/')

    with open('media/classification/' + filename, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)

def image_classification(request):

    form_des = ItemForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' in request.FILES:
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'], str(request.FILES['file']))

            img = np.expand_dims(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(os.path.join('./media/classification/', str(request.FILES['file']))), (170, 100)), axis=0)
            cat_prediction = cat_classifier.predict_classes(img)[0]
            pattern_prediction = pat_classifier.predict_classes(img)[0]

            form_des.fields['title'].widget.attrs['value'] = cat_prediction
            form_des.fields['pattern'].widget.attrs['value'] = pattern_prediction

            return render(request, 'upload_item.html', {'form_des': form_des})

    return HttpResponse('failed')
```

**upload_image.html template**

```
{% block content %}
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-8">
    <center>
      <h2>Upload image</h2>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
          <form action="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}image_classification/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class='first_form'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" />
            <label for="file" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-lg btn-block select mt-5">Choose a file</label>

            <input class='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block' type="submit" value="Upload image" />
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class='font-weight-bold mt-5'>Step: 1 of 2</p>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**upload_item.html template**

```
{% block content %}
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-6">
    <center>
      <h2>Item description</h2>

    </center>
    <div class="card mb-5 mt-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{form_des|crispy}}
          <button type="submit" class='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block save_btn'>Save item</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <center><p class='font-weight-bold mt-5'>Step: 2 of 2</p></center>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Please help me

Thank you

PS: Not sure if the title of the question is relevant to the content. I could not think of a proper title for this question. Sorry of the same.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the overall architecture here, but it seems that none of your forms go to the `upload_item` view. The first has an `action` sending it to the `image_classification` view, and the second has no `action` so it gets POSTed back to the same URL. I guess the easiest fix to what you want is just to add the appropriate `action` attribute to that second form?

Comment: I tried that. the second form should save the item and display it in the items_list template. so I tried adding `action='../..'` to the second form. but this just displayed an empty items_list template. which means the form was not saved

Comment: Well that's a bad way to handle your URLs, because if you ever change them so that the destination is no longer 2 levels "up" in the URL tree from where the form is, your code will break. Much better to use the `{% url %}` template tag, especially since you're already giving `name`s to  your URL patterns which can use this. But more to the point, this looks like the wrong URL. It looks like the relevant view function is the `upload_item` one, so the relevant URL appears to be `items/upload/description/` (I'm only giving the absolute path so you can see the difference from what you have)

Comment: I tried adding the action to the form. now it gives me a 404 error. the path becomes `http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/upload/image_classification/%7Burl%20'upload_item'%7D`. this is the code i added. `action="{url 'upload_item'}"`

Comment: looks like you left out the `%` signs: `{% url 'upload_item' %}`

Comment: Oops. The code works now. Thank you so much. One thing I did not understand is why am I directing to the same page with actions in the form when I have to go to the items_list template. I am still a beginner with forms and do not understand them completely.

Comment: Happy to help. The `action` attribute is just the URL to which the `POST` (or `GET`) request goes - and since you're using Django, you will have a view function that handles that request. (Specified in your `urls.py`.) I would recommed this page for the basics of HTML forms: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data